# Magento 2 recently ordered block add to cart button

Tags: magento2.2

I am experiencing an issue with the recently ordered block which is positioned on category pages in Magento 2.2.

After the customer orders products, they should show in this block as a list of recently ordered items.

They show normally, but without the add to cart button

[image]

All of the products are in stock and enabled.

By default the `Magento_Sales/templates/reorder/sidebar.phtml` template is used to show this block.

This piece of code makes the Add to cart button show or not:

```
<div class="primary no-display"
    data-bind="css: {'no-display': !lastOrderedItems().isShowAddToCart}">
    <button type="submit" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>" class="action tocart primary">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Seems that `!lastOrderedItems().isShowAddToCart` returns `true`...I'm just not sure why.

There is no display: none property which is out of place. The **no-display** class gives it the display: none property. And this class depends on the result of **!lastOrderedItems().isShowAddToCart**.

As far as I can see, this is in Luma theme also in default Magento 2.2, but it is bypassed by Luma's additional css (display: block is added to this element with custom css).

Since this is basically default Magento 2.2 code, what am I missing? Is this a default bug or?

Comment: I could not reproduce the case you are talking about. It seems like some of the products are not saleable.

Comment: I would recommend you to inspect the add to cart button and div surrounding it. Check the css as well, there might be display:none for that dom element.

Comment: There is no display:none which is out of place. The **no-display** class gives it the display:none css property. And this class depends on the result of **!lastOrderedItems().isShowAddToCart**. As far as I can see, this is in Luma theme also, but it is bypassed by additional ccs (display:block is added to this element).